# Display data in php using for loop

Tags: php, loops

I have two variable `$a = 11550,` and `$b = 275;`

i want to display in table row in loop

```
1. 11550
2. 11275
3. 11000
4. 10725
```

n number of times.

Thanks

Comment: what have you done till now?

Comment: And where is the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Rizier123 i want to print only 5 row

Comment: @sudhirsingh Show your current code/attempt.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you achieve the desired output:

```
<?php

    $a = 11550;
    $b = 275;

    $start_value = 11550;

    $output = '<table border="1">';
    while ($start_value > 0){
        $start_value = $start_value - $b;

        $output .= '<tr><td>'.$start_value.'</td></tr>';
    }

    $output .= '</table>';

    echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: If you'd just output it in a table, then your answer seems correct !

Comment: thanks. but how can print in for loop with number of rows in table td

Comment: @sudhirsingh sorry but did not understand your question.

Comment: i want to print only 5 rows

Answer (score 0):

```
while($a>0) {
    echo $a = $a - $b . "</br>";
}
```

If you want to do this 5 times only then set $n = 5

```
$n = 5;
for($i=0; $i<$n; $i++) { 
    echo $a = $a - $b . "</br>";
}
```

Comment: I want print only 5 times

Comment: Use for loop then  for($i=0; $i<5; $i++) { echo $a = $a - $b . "</br>"; }

Answer (score 0):

Solution with `range`, `array_reverse`(for descending order) functions and adjustable step (**n**) parameter:

```
$end = 11550;
$step = 275;
$n = 10;

$start = $end - $n * $step;
$range = ($start >= 0)? range($start, $end, $step) : null;

if (!empty($range)) {
    $output = '<table border="1">';
    $reversed = array_reverse($range);
    foreach ($reversed as $val) {
        $output .= '<tr><td>'.$val.'</td></tr>';
    }
    $output .= '</table>';
    echo $output;
}
```

the output will be as shown below:

```html
<table border="1"><tr><td>11550</td></tr><tr><td>11275</td></tr><tr><td>11000</td></tr><tr><td>10725</td></tr><tr><td>10450</td></tr><tr><td>10175</td></tr><tr><td>9900</td></tr><tr><td>9625</td></tr><tr><td>9350</td></tr><tr><td>9075</td></tr><tr><td>8800</td></tr></table>
```